# Items not moving back to Draft when edited in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-workflow

We have a site with a very basic workflow for items. It's Draft > Queue for publish (action) > Ready for publish. Authors work on and item, then click "Queue for publish", thus moving the item in to the final "Ready for publish state. We have an agent that is auto publishing, which will pick it up next time around or they can also choose to manually publish the item.

Most of this works, except that when and item is in the final state, my understanding is that the action of editing it, should automatically create a new version and send the item back to draft. This is not happening.

Is there something specific we need to add to workflow to make this happen? Or, is there a step authors need to take to do this. Any other recommendations would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same experience when I turned off the locking.

Automatically creat a new version by an edit in a workflow works when, you have require locking on.

```
      <!--  REQUIRE LOCK BEFORE EDITING
        If true, the user must have a lock on a document before
        he can edit it, otherwise it is always ready for editing
      -->
  <setting name="RequireLockBeforeEditing" value="true"/>
```

Also a admin have no require locking, and not automatic a new version when edit a item as admin. (same as Trayek say)

Comment: yeah, that's what it was. We had that turned off. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are your authors in the `Administrator` role? Anyone in the Administrator role will have to manually start workflow process. A new version will also not be created when editing I believe.

Also, if you create a new item based on your defined template, does Sitecore correctly add it to the workflow? If not, it might suggest you haven't set up the workflow correctly (unless, again, the users are administrators). All you need to do to set up your workflow is in your template's `__Standard Values` you need to set the `Default Workflow` field to your workflow